# Android Google Play how to get longer stacktrace?

Tags: android, stack-trace, google-play

There's error report functionality in Google Play. Is there a way to increase the length of the stacktraces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are probably better off using libraries like [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/)